# Do I need vagrant for installation edx platform on Ubuntu 12.04 for getting through AWS step

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, vagrant, edx

I try to install edx platform on ubuntu 12.04 by this tutorial https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Ubuntu-12.04-64-bit-Installation. I don't use Vagrant but on step `[aws | update the ssh motd on Ubuntu]` I've got error `fatal: [localhost] => error while evaluating conditional: vagrant_home_dir.stat.exists == false`. It is strange, because tutorial helps to install edx without vagrant. Why do I get errors about not existing vagrant?

This section, I mean `aws`, goes after `certs`. Take a look there https://github.com/edx/configuration/blob/master/playbooks/edx_sandbox.yml#L51. So... I'm not sure what will be installed by this, but it seems it related to Amazon Web Services. After a little search information about AWS and edx, I've got, that edx can be installed on AWS. But I install edx on my VPS, and it confused me more. Maybe I don't need get through this step. Maybe I don't understand something yet.

Sorry if my english is not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ansible task which gives you error is `update the ssh motd on Ubuntu`
it is located in `configuration/playbooks/roles/aws/tasks/main.yml`
this task is for updating the ssh modt on ubuntu, it removes some of the default motd display on ubuntu and add a custom motd.This is needed for EC2 instances.

```
- name: update the ssh motd on Ubuntu
  file: >
    mode=0644
    path={{ item }}
  when: vagrant_home_dir.stat.exists == false
  with_items:
  - "/etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text"
  - "/usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper"
  - "/etc/update-motd.d/51-cloudguest"
  - "/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade"
```

Since you are not using an EC2 instance you can skip this one by commenting it out.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!